# How to edit ~/.xinitrc to run tilix??

Tags: archlinux

I've been installing Arch Linux. I finished installing and was setting up my desktop.. I have downloaded Xorg. By default ~/.xinitrc will start the basic environment with twm, xorg-xclock and xterm. But instead of twm and xterm I would like to use i3wm and tilix respectively. I edited by ~/.xinitrc to run i3wm but couldn't find how to edit it to run tilix. I have already tried editing it by replacing xterm with tilix. But it does not seem to be working since when I ran startx the terminal did not appear. Can somebody please tell me how to edit the ~/.xinitrc file so that it runs tilix instead of xterm?

Answer (score 1):

Default terminal is not controlled by .xintrc

Two solutions:

- Add `export TERMINAL=tilix` to `~/.bashrc`
- Find your i3 config file (usually located at `~/.config/i3/config` or `~/.i3/config`)
  and change `bindsym $mod+Return exec i3-sensible-terminal` 
  to `bindsym $mod+Return exec tilix`

For automatically launching terminal at startup, read https://i3wm.org/docs/userguide.html (part 4.17).